# Tocar used for winning vs ganar?

Tags: verbos

Excerpt from a Spanish lesson:
Compré un boleto de lotería y estoy imaginando cómo cambiaría mi vida si me tocara.
Translation ?:
I bought a lottery ticket, and I'm imagining how my life would change if I won.
Question: 
Why not use ganar?
Compré un billete de lotería y me estoy imaginando cómo cambiaría mi vida si me gané.

Comment: When I was a child, I frequently heard "sacarse la lotería",  although this may have been local to Chile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ganar* is used for the overall concept: the lottery

> ...cómo cambiaría mi vida si me tocara

But this sentence is not talking about the generic (the lottery) but about one of its components: a lottery ticket (un boleto de la lotería).

In this case, it's not "winning the ticket" (ganar el boleto), but from of all the possible tickets, getting the winning ticket: *que me toque el boleto ganador*.

> ...cómo cambiaría mi vida si ganase la lotería

> ...cómo cambiaría mi vida si me tocase el boleto ganador

Answer (score 0):

El hecho de que en esta cuestión expresamente no se haya utilizado el verbo "ganar" no significa que no se utilice, así se puede decir "Tocar la lotería"  o "Ganar a la lotería".

> The fact that in this question the verb "**ganar**" has not been
> expressly used does not mean that it is not used, thus it can be said
> "**Tocar la lotería**" or "**Ganar a la lotería**".

- "Compré un boleto de lotería y estoy imaginando cómo cambiaría mi vida si ganara"
- "Compré un décimo (se sobrentiende décimo o billete de lotería) y me estoy imaginando cómo cambiaría mi vida si ganara (la lotería)".
- "Compré un décimo y me estoy imaginando cómo cambiaría mi vida si ganara la lotería".

Así "**ganar la lotería**" o "**tocar la lotería**" son perfectamente válidos.

> So "**ganar la lotería**" or "**tocar la lotería**" are perfectly valid.

Específicamente cuando hablamos de "**Tocar**",  uno de los significados en este contexto es, "**caer en suerte**" o "**corresponder algo a alguien por azar**". Así en este caso quien "**te toca es es la suerte**", la suerte, de forma figurativa, es la que te ha "**tocado**", dándote la oportunidad de ganar, en este caso, "la lotería".

> Specifically when we talk about "**Tocar**", one of the meanings in this
> context is, "**caer en suerte** (to fall into luck)" or " **corresponder**
> **algo a alguien por azar** (to correspond something to someone by
> chance)". So in this case who "**te toca la suerte** (touches you is
> luck)", luck, figuratively, is the one that has "tocado (touched
> you)", giving you the opportunity to win, in this case, "la lotería".

P.D. Si **ganas en la lotería** uno de los mejores premios se puede decir "**Gané el Gordo**" o "**Me tocó el Gordo**".

> P.S. If you **ganas en la lotería** one of the best prizes can be said
> "**Gané el Gordo (Win el Gordo)**" or "**Me tocó el Gordo**".

"**Tocar el Gordo**" (La suerte del gran premio cayó sobre mi).

> "**Tocar el Gordo**" (The luck of the grand prize fell on me).

---

Otros usos del verbo "Tocar"

> Other uses of the verb "Tocar"

¿Quién nos "toca" ahora? - Ahora le "toca" al profesor de Matemáticas.

En este caso "tocar" se refiere al turno de alguien.

> In this case "tocar" refers to someone's turn.

¿De quién es el turno ahora? Ahora tiene el turno el profesor de Matemáticas.

Otro ejemplo

¿A quién le toca llevar a los niños al colegio? - Esta semana me toca a mi

Significa que el turno de llevar a los niños esta semana lo hago yo.

> It's my turn to take the kids this week ("lo hago yo" "es mi turno" -
> "me toca a mi").